# How to avoid Round-up from NormalizeDouble and OrderSend Pending Order (SELLLIMIT, BUYLIMIT) get Error -1 Invalid stops

Tags: mql4

Please advice me how to solve problem when OrderSend Pending Order ( BUYLIMIT, SELLLIMIT) got error -1 Invalid stops.

also tell me the rule of BUYLIMIT and SELLLIMIT.

the simple code like below:

`

```
double  digit = MarketInfo(symbol,MODE_DIGITS);
    POPRICE  = NormalizeDouble(BBMVAL[0],digit);
    TPPRICE  = NormalizeDouble(POPRICE + (30*point),digit)
    SLPRICE  = NormalizeDouble(POPRICE - (30*point),digit)

    ticket1=OrderSend(symbol,OP_BUYLIMIT,0.1, POPRICE,Slippage,SLPRICE,TPPRICE,BUYLIMIT,magic,(TimeCurrent()+(3600*2)),CLR_NONE);

          Sleep(10);
          while(IsTradeContextBusy()) Sleep(100);
          RefreshRates();
          if(ticket1 < 0)
               {
                  SendMail
                     (
                        symbol+"-"+ IntegerToString(Period())+"-" + "FAILED-BUYLIMIT ", 
                        symbol+"-"+ IntegerToString(Period())+"-" + "FAILED-BUYLIMIT "+"(#PO-Price:"+POPRICE+"#TP:"+TPPRICE++"#SL:"+SLPRICE+"#RespID:"+ticket1+"#Status: "+ErrorDescription(GetLastError())+")"          
                     );
                  ticket1 = 0;   
               }


          if (ticket1 > 0)
               {
                   b_Status = 1;
                   SendMail
                      (
                         symbol+"-"+ IntegerToString(Period())+"-" + "SUCCESSED-BUYLIMIT ", 
                         symbol+"-"+ IntegerToString(Period())+"-" + "SUCCESSED-BUYLIMIT "+"(#PO-    Price:"+POPRICE+"#TP:"+TPPRICE+"#SL:"+SLPRICE+"#RespID:"+ticket1+"#Status: "+ErrorDescription(GetLastError())+")"         
                      );
                   ticket1 = 0;   
               }
```

the objective is :

1. If the pair EURUSD 5-digit, How to make the SLPRICE, POPRICE, TPPRICE always with 5-digit. sometimes with 5 digit and sometime roundup with 4-digit. is it right to use NormalizeDouble ? how to avoid the roundup.
2. when got Failed ( tiket1 < 0 ), the error is -1 ( invalid stops), what is the real reason of this error.  sometimes successed and sometime failed. what is the rules of selllimit and the buylimit.
   and when got Failed, there are many emails send to email-address. how to avoid this problem too.

THank you very much.

Comment: It is okay to have a 4-digit price if you have 5-digit feed. 1.28980 = 1.2898.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly okay to have a 4 digit price when 5 digit decimal is expected, but since `double` is a floating-point number, sometimes you don't get the exact price you might expect,

for example: 
let's say you are calculating TP for a long trade, `1.10000 + 0.0020 = 1.10020`(expected) but you might get something like this `1.10020001`, in these cases the price level is rejected, causing errors. That is why price normalizing is important.

In some pairs, you might find that `NormalizeDouble()` sometimes gives false values, in those cases use the following function.

```
double NP(const double price)
{
   double tickSize = SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(), SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE);
   return (MathRound(price / tickSize) * tickSize );
}
```

As for getting the many emails: you can limit the number of emails per period of time.

Here I made it so that you get 1 email per new candle:

```
if(ticket1 < 0)
{
   static datetime prevTime = 0;

   if(Time[0] > prevTime)
   {
      SendMail
      (
         symbol + "-" + IntegerToString(Period()) + "-" + "FAILED-BUYLIMIT ",
         symbol + "-" + IntegerToString(Period()) + "-" + "FAILED-BUYLIMIT " + "(#PO-Price:" + POPRICE + "#TP:" + TPPRICE++"#SL:" + SLPRICE + "#RespID:" + ticket1 + "#Status: " + ErrorDescription(GetLastError()) + ")"
      );
      prevTime = Time[0];
   }
   ticket1 = 0;
}
```